# How can I repair a gap between drywall and stairs?

Tags: drywall, repair, stairs, cracks

I have a 110-year character home and the stairs going to my finished basement needs some attention.  Specifically, where the drywall meets the stairs, the material is cracking and flaking away and creating a small gap where the stairs meet the drywall.  Any advice or suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It would help if we could see what you see. Maybe a few pics. You can edit them into your question.

Comment: What is "a 110-year character home" anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I guessing that with a 110 year old house and flaking material that you meant plaster instead of drywall. I have had to address the same in my 100 year old home.

- Clean away all lose material.
- Run a length of painters tape above and below the gap and mask the stair underneath
  with paper. If you haven't used it before foam is messy and hard to clean up. Use
  gloves.
- Then use canned expanding foam to fill the gap between the plaster and trim letting
  some of it adhere to the base layer (lathe, base coat plaster). Some of it will drop
  down in the wall. It takes some practice to get it to stick where you want. For really
  large gaps use hi-expansion foam.
- Let dry completely overnight then trim excess with a sharp knife.
- Finish wall with drywall compound using fiberglass mesh tape and mesh sheet for any
  bigger patches. If any of the dried foam protrudes past where you need it push it in to
  compress it with a blunt piece of wood.

Comment: You cannot answer this without seeing a picture.   You may be right or you may be way wrong.

Comment: You are correct. I may be either of those as any other person that answers a question can be.  But the OP asked for suggestions on a fix and to me that is one possible simple fix to the condition that I have observed the most on homes of this age. Stringers settle and the gap shows up.